# Assign the Background rule in Grid (the positions can be described by a integer function)

Tags: grid-layouts, rule

For example, this code

```
Grid[Transpose[Table[{n, n^2}, {n, 1, 10}]], Frame -> All, 
Background -> {{1 -> Red, 4 -> Red, 9 -> Red}}]
```

produces

[image],

in this case, the columns has column number being a square integer, i.e the 1,4,9,16,25...etc. columns

This second code does the same job:

```
rule = {};
Do[If[IntegerQ[Sqrt[i]], AppendTo[rule, i -> Red]], {i, 1, 10}]
Grid[Transpose[Table[{n, n^2}, {n, 1, 10}]], Frame -> All, Background -> {rule}]
```

or better

```
rule = {};
Do[AppendTo[rule, i^2 -> Red], {i, 1, 10}]
Grid[Transpose[Table[{n, n^2}, {n, 1, 10}]], Frame -> All, Background -> {rule}]
```

I wonder if there is a way to specify a rule, in the 3rd way, inside Grid[] directly.

Comment: You can use `SparseArray` for `Background`.

Comment: `IntegerQ[Sqrt[i]]` is a given so you can just enter say `Background -> {Thread[Range[5]^2 -> Red]}`

Answer (score 3):

For the record:

```
Grid[Transpose[Table[{n, n^2}, {n, 1, 10}]], Frame -> All, 
     Background -> {Normal @ SparseArray[i_ :> Red /; IntegerQ[Sqrt[i]], 10, White]}]
```

Of course Mike`s way is way shorter so I'd use it here but I think this one can be used im more complicated cases.